# How can I add Items to my sessionStorage in a little amount of code?

Tags: javascript

I want my users to click on different `<a>`s. After clicking on two of them I want to lead my user to another site.
A different combination of clicked `<a>`s should lead to a different site.

I basically know, how to do it, but my code would be very, very long and it would take a lot of time to fill in every command for each combination.

As I am relatively new to javascript, I have no idea how to shorten my code.

Until now, this is my code:

```
var stufe = sessionStorage.getItem('stufe');
var fach = sessionStorage.getItem("fach");

if(stufe == "c5"){
          if(fach == "deutsch"){

          }
          else if(fach == "deutsch"){

          }
          else if(fach == "mathe"){

          }
          else if(fach == "englisch"){

          }
          else if(fach == "religion"){

          }
          else if(fach == "musik"){

          }
          else if(fach == "kunst"){

          }
          else if(fach == "geografie"){

          }
          else if(fach == "sport"){

          }
          else if(fach == "bio"){

          }
          else if(fach == "chemie"){

          }
          else if(fach == "physik"){

          }
          else if(fach == "französisch"){

          }
          else if(fach == "latein"){

          }
          else if(fach == "nwt"){

          }
          else if(fach == "imp"){

          }
          else if(fach == "italienisch"){

          }
          else if(fach == "deutsch"){

          }
          else if(fach == "deutsch"){

          }
          else if(fach == "deutsch"){

          }
          else if(fach == "deutsch"){

          }
          else if(fach == "deutsch"){

          }
          else if(fach == "deutsch"){

          }
          else if(fach == "deutsch"){

          }
        }
```

It will be repeated again at least five times. And I would have to fill in `window.location.replace(...)`
under each `else if()`.
So the code would be huge.

It's all in German, so if you need any translation, please tell me.
As well if there is any information missing, please tell me.

I hope you can help me.
Daniel.

Comment: Can you give some examples to the sites you want to redirect to ?

Comment: Is it necessary to mention the content of the sites? Because I havent done it yet. But for the beginning it would be enough to lead my users to Youtube, twitter or anything else. I would fill in the path later.
Important is that I can insert an individual site for each combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have an object with the following structure for each of your subjects, the object keys would be the route name and the value the route to navigate to:

```
const subjects = {
  chemie: 'url-to-chemie...',
  bio: 'url-to-bio...',
  kust: 'url-to-kust...',
  sport: 'url-to-sport...',
}
```

And instead of all your if's you could, assuming navigate is a function that navigates to a given url:

```
navigate(subjects[fach]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found a solution on my own now. But if my solution won’t work, I will come back to your answer.